# How do I keep track of the total_money in savings account (using classes)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need help containing the data inputted with dollars and cents. I've been trying by putting it in a total_money equation, but I'am stuck. For example, when I deposit 30 dollars I want it to stay there so when I go back in a deposit 10 dollars I get 40.

This is all about depositing and withdrawing money from a bank account while it keeps track of the total money left in the account by using classes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount
{
public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(int d, int c);
    void deposit(int d, int c);
    void withdraw(int d, int c);
    void total(int d, int c);
    void set(int dollars, int cents);
    void convert(int d, int c);
private:
    double total_money;
    int dollars;
    int cents;
};

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount()
{
    dollars = 0;
    cents = 0;
}
void SavingsAccount::set(int dollars, int cents)
{

}

int main()
{
    SavingsAccount bank1, bank2(50, 88);
    int dollars, cents;
    bank1.set(30, 65);
    bank2.set(0, 0);
    int anwser;
    cout << "Would you like to 1.Deposit or 2.Withdraw?";
    cin >> anwser;
    if (anwser == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter in how much you want to deposit in dollars:";
        cin >> dollars;
        cout << "Enter in how much you want to deposit in cents:";
        cin >> cents;
        if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        bank1.deposit(dollars, cents);//should call upon the seprate deposit funtction below
    }
    else if (anwser == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter in how much you want to withdraw in dollars:";
        cin >> dollars;
        cout << "Enter in how much you want to withdraw in cents:";
        cin >> cents;
        if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0)
        {
            cerr << "Invalid!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        bank1.withdraw(dollars, cents);
    }

}
SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(int d, int c)
{
    dollars = d;
    cents = c;

}
void SavingsAccount::convert(int d, int c)
{

    dollars = dollars + c / 100;
    cents = c % 100;//% used for the remainer
}


void SavingsAccount::deposit(int d, int c)
{
    dollars += d;//d is where the program keeps track of the values
    cents += c;
    if (cents >= 100)
    {
        convert(d, c);
    }
    //total_money=???
    total(dollars, cents);
}

void SavingsAccount::withdraw(int d, int c)
{
    dollars += d;
    cents += c;
    if (cents >= 100)
    {
        convert(c, d);
    }
    //total_money=???
    total(dollars, cents);
}

void SavingsAccount::total(int d, int c)
{
    cout << "Total money: " <<d<<"."<< c<< endl;

}
```

Comment: You'll have better accuracy if you use an integer variable for pennies and only convert to dollars when printing.  If you want greater accuracy, then have an integer represent 1/100 of a penny.  Search the internet for "fixed point arithmetic".

Comment: I see no use for member variables `total_money` and `sumDollarsCents`

Comment: total_money is supposed to keep the amount of money I've put in and either add to it or subtract if I wish to withdraw. I'm having trouble with how to do that though.

Comment: @Mr.Mafia your code is not even *trying* to update `total_money`, that is the problem. You need something like this: `void SavingsAccount::deposit(int d, int c) { dollars += d; cents += c; if (cents >= 100) { dollars += (cents / 100); cents %= 100; } total_money = dollars + (double(cents) / 100); }`  See why it is not a good idea to track `dollars` and `cents` separately? It just makes the logic ugly and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be a little messy and there are some wrong things happening here:

1. The method `set()` does nothing.
2. The field `total_money` is never initialized, set or queried.
3. The `main()` method somehow landed between the implementations of `SavingsAccount`, which is not a problem but makes your code harder to read.
4. `convert` is a non-static member function, so why don't you use the fields `dollars` and `cents` directly by first checking for a cent overflow and then modifying them in the overflow case.
5. In the method `deposit()`, the member variables are updated as expected. But then, `convert()` is called with the methods parameters and not with the fields. This will not change `dollars` or `cents` in any way (best to implement `convert()` as described in 4). At the end, you call `total()` again with the field values, which weren't converted.
6. The method `withdraw()` does exactly the same as `deposit()`. Did you mean to use `-=`?
7. `total()` does nothing else than printing the value. First, this could again be done using the fields instead of parameters (as it is not static), and second, you should rename this method to something like `print()` and parameterize it with an ostream.
8. Depending on how you would change your code, some methods may as well be private.

A well-formed program could look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount {
    unsigned int dollars;
    unsigned int cents;
    double total_money; //actually not necessary

    static double getDoubleVal(unsigned int, unsigned int);
    void convert();

public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(unsigned int, unsigned int);
    void setValues(unsigned int, unsigned int);
    void deposit(unsigned int, unsigned int);
    void withdraw(unsigned int, unsigned int);

    ostream& print(ostream&) const;
}

double SavingsAccount::getDoubleVal(unsigned int d, unsigned int c) {
    return d + (c / 100.0);
}

void SavingsAccount::convert() {
    dollars += cents / 100 //integer divison on purpose
    cents %= 100;
    total_money = getDoubleVal(dollars, cents);
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount() : dollars{ 0 }, cents{ 0 }, total_money{ 0.0 } {
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(unsigned int d, unsigned int c) : dollars{ d }, cents{ c }, total_money{ getDoubleVal(d, c) } {
    convert();
}

void SavingsAccount::setValues(unsigned int d, unsigned int c) {
    dollars = d;
    cents = c;
    convert();
}

void SavingsAccount::deposit(unsigned int d, unsigned int c) {
    setValues(dollars + d, cents + c);
}

void SavingsAccount::withdraw(unsigned int d, unsigned int c) {
    //You should also check for unsigned int underflow here
    setValues(dollars - d, cents - c);
}

ostream& SavingsAccount::print(ostream& o) const {
    o << total_money;
    return o;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const SavingsAccount& sa) {
    return sa.print(o);
}

int main() {
    SavingsAccount sa1 = SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount sa2 = SavingsAccount(1337, 42);
    cout << sa1 << sa2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes in the code, especially formatting, I wrote this on my phone...